# Filter virtual machine name which contains string with Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm looking for a way to filter virtual machine name which contains string "myvm" using Azure Python SDK. I tried the following way but it seems not to work

```
for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_by_location(LOCATION):
            print(vm.name)
            if vm.name in "myvm":
```

the If condition seems not to be able to query in the list of virtual machines.

Comment: `if vm.name == "myvm":`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 sorry for not being clear. I'd like to query all vms whose name contains string "myvm"

Comment: i think it should be `if 'myvm' in vm.name:`. I dont think you can filter when you query, i dont think there is a method for that, at least in the compute sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to reverse the `in`, because you are checking for the existence of `myvmname1` in `myvm`. obviously this wont work, because `myvmname1` is not in the string `myvm`.